# Как правильно передать в button.Content string?

Tags: c#, wpf

Цель задачи - вывести имена груп на кнопки. 
Из-за того что я выгружаю именна из базы данных, я генерирую кнопки. 

Код генерации:

```
private void LoadAllGroups()
    {
        foreach (var item in groupService.GetId())
        {
            Button btn = new Button();
            btn.FontSize = 30;  
            btn.Height = 50;
            btn.Width = 400;
            btn.Content = groupService.GetGroupName().ToString();
            groupPanel.Children.Add(btn);
        }
    }
```

Весь сок в `btn.Content = groupService.GetGroupName()` 
 так как когда я присваиваю метод который ретурнит IEnumerable в контенте кнопки показывает не стринг, а `system.linq.enumerable+whereselectenumerableiterator`  

Собствено метод:

```
public IEnumerable<string> GetGroupName()
    {
        return unitOfWork.GroupRepository.Get().Select(a => a.Name);
    }
```

Буду благодарен если кто-то подскажет как выводить на кнопку имя которое ретурнит метод!

Comment: Не как, забудьте про это раз и на всегда! WPF это привязки, WPF это XAML разметка, используйте их.

Comment: Вы это серьезно? Вам говорят, что вы совершаете огромнейшую ошибку, говорят, что так делать в принципе нельзя, говорят как надо, а вместо того, чтобы прислушаться, оскорбляете? Ну тогда простите, а какой смысл вообще задавать тут вопрос, если вы не в силах обучаться? Еще раз повторю, у вас **не должно** быть в коде создания кнопочек и прочего, этому место в XAML, где будет, например `ItemsControl`, который будет иметь внутри вид "кнопки", а сам привязанный к некому `public ObservableCollection<Group> Groups {get;}`, все, вот ваша задача в несколько строк кода, но нет, делаем кнопки в коде..

Comment: Всё верно вам говорит @EvgeniyZ. Несмотря на его прямолинейность и быть может недостаточный уровень вежливости (имхо), он мощный эксперт в WPF. Берите ItemsControl, задайте ему шаблон элемента (ItemTemplate) как кнопку, берите ObservableCollection, реализуйте INotifyPropertyChanged в классе для свойства с коллекцией и готово. Обязательно почитайте про MVVM в WPF, и зачем оно нужно. Примеры реализаций можете посмотреть в [моих прошых ответах](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A373567+itemscontrol). WPF это не Winforms, здесь всё по-другому, и оно того стоит, чтобы изучить.

Comment: @aepot Ах этот мир, ах этот SO. Меня тут матом поливают, а я "недостаточно вежливый". Чтож...

Comment: @EvgeniyZ ну, когда есть оправдание невежливости - это всё меняет, конечно (но это не точно) :) Я вас понимаю, но люди разные бывают, это ж публичный ресурс, будьте снисходительны. Не каждый человек способен переварить прямоту, некоторые скатываются в агрессию.

Comment: Я разве писал что-то об MVVM? Я не хочу реализовать этот паттерн!
Мне нужен совет в обстоятельствах которые я описал! @EvgeniyZ

Comment: @PurplePig Вы от меня хоть слово увидели про MVVM? Я вам не говорю про него, я говорю про самые базовые вещи WPF, а именно XAML. Если вы им не пользуетесь, то вопрос: а зачем вообще вы сидите на WPF? MVVM, это подход отделения интерфейса от логики, я хоть слова про это сказал? Нет. Вы можете написать `<ItemsControl x:Name="myItems">` и в коде `myItems.ItemsSource = groupService.GetGroupName()`, эт оооч грубое нарушение MVVM, но яж вам это не запрещаю. Вы сейчас сами себе злой буратино, который делает вред и кучу лишнего, ведь создавать кнопки за вас должен **автоматически сам WPF**, вот и все.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы итерировались не по тому перечислению, то есть item получали, но никак не использовали. Если взять то что вам нужно, то код получится такой:

```cs
foreach (var item in groupService.GetGroupName())
{
    Button btn = new Button
    {
        FontSize = 30,
        Height = 50,
        Width = 400,
        Content = item
    };
    groupPanel.Children.Add(btn);
}
```

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin постарался, раз уж вы настаиваете.

Comment: 1. я просил, а не настаивал. 2. наверно, в первую очередь стоило объяснить, что именно у автора вопроса было "не так"

Comment: @aepot Спасибо, вы мне помогли! Благодарен!